# apache pig: converting bags to columns.

Tags: apache-pig, bag

I've a PIG question and is related to converting bags to columns, details as follows:

```
(267720, {(201607),(201606),(201605)}, {(1),(3),(0)})
(806571, {(201607),(201606),(201605)}, {(28),(76),(75)})
```

I want to convert it to:

```
266720 201607 1
266720 201606 3
266720 201605 0 
806571 201607 28
806571 201606 76 
806571 201605 75
```

I tried:

```
JG3 = FOREACH JG2 GENERATE company_id, flatten(date) as date, Flatten(new_hire) as newhire;
```

But can not achieve the exact match between date and newhire, there will be duplicate dates.

Does anyone know how I should do this in Pig? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Way you are doing will create cartesian product of date and new_hire column. If you have control over this data - do this mapping before you create bags. If not then you have to write udf to generate this one to one mapping.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Pig and never used UDF before, can you give more detailed information about what kind of UDF I should create?

Answer (score 0):

Use ToBag()

```
JG3 = FOREACH JG2 GENERATE company_id, FLATTEN(TOBAG($1)), FLATTEN(TOBAG($2));
```